# FULL OUTER JOIN on two pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, outer-join

I have two datafames df1 and df2. i want to create a output dataframe. The join column between both the dataframes is 'ID'. I am trying Full outer join but looks like it is not supported.
I am new to python so any help is appreciated

**df1**

| ID | A | B | C | D | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-06 | Sam | CA | Y | text |
| 2 | 2021-05-07 | Tom | CY |  | text |
| 3 | 2021-05-08 | Jerry | MA | Y | text |

**df2**

| ID | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-09 | Sam | CA |
| 2 | 2021-05-09 | Tom | CY |
| 3 | 2021-05-09 | Jerry | MA |
| 5 | 2021-05-09 | Victor | CA |
| 6 | 2021-05-09 | Dick | CY |
| 7 | 2021-05-09 | John | MA |

**Output**

| ID | A | B | C | D | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-06 | Sam | CA | Y | text |
| 2 | 2021-05-07 | Tom | CY |  | text |
| 3 | 2021-05-08 | Jerry | MA | Y | text |
| 5 | 2021-05-09 | Victor | CA |  |  |
| 6 | 2021-05-09 | Dick | CY |  |  |
| 7 | 2021-05-09 | John | MA |  |  |

Answer (score 1):

Let's try `pandas.DataFrame.append`. The documentation is available [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['1', '2021-05-06', 'Sam', 'CA', 'Y', 'text'],
                    ['2', '2021-05-07', 'Tom', 'CY', np.nan, 'text'], 
                    ['3', '2021-05-08', 'Jerry', 'MA', 'Y', 'text']], 
                     columns = ['ID', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['1', '2021-05-09', 'Sam', 'CA'],
                    ['2', '2021-05-09', 'Tom', 'CY'],
                    ['3', '2021-05-09', 'Jerry', 'MA'], 
                    ['4', '2021-05-09', 'Victor', 'CA'], 
                    ['5', '2021-05-09', 'Dick', 'CY'],
                    ['6', '2021-05-09', 'John', 'MA']], 
                     columns = ['ID', 'A', 'B', 'C'])

df1_ID_list = df1['ID'].unique().tolist()

df_result = df1.append(df2.loc[~(df2['ID'].isin(df1_ID_list))], sort = False)
```

[image]